# javascript: make a iframe to get the x&y of mouse

Tags: javascript, animation, iframe

I have an iframe

```
<iframe id="EXAMPLE"></iframe>
```

edited:
How can I make the iframe to get the mouse cordinaes on real time with javascript?

Comment: Add more information for your question. What do you want to do?

Comment: Animate the iframe? What does animation have to do with the mouse position?

Comment: What does the `iframe` have to do with getting mouse coordinates?

Comment: i just want that the ifreame to get the mouse positions on real time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML you have this:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com" id="test"></iframe>
```

Set some CSS styles:

```
body {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: black;
}

#test {
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Now, you have to get the mouse position on document. You can use jQuery `mousemove` handler:

```
$("body").on("mousemove", function(e) {
    console.log("X: " + e.clientX + "px Y: " + e.clientY + "px");
});
```

Then, set the `iframe` position on document:

```
function update(e) {
    $("#test").css("left", e.clientX + 10 + "px");
    $("#test").css("top", e.clientY + 10 + "px");
}
```

Now, just simply call `update` function inside of `mousemove`.

See live preview [here](http://goo.gl/a8jBN).

If you want to detect `mousemove` on `iframe`, too, add `pointer-events:none` to `iframe` styles. Tested [here](http://goo.gl/f96qn).

[image]

Comment: @user1898399, click [here](http://goo.gl/cMJy6) to see fullscreen document. I am glad I helped you.